# Ударник труда: кого ударяем?

Tags: употребление-слов

"Ударный труд", "ударник труда". Интересно, а почему тут речь об ударе? Кого ударяем и зачем?))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю, сохранилось ли точное указание на профессию, которая понималась "авторами" этого слова, но несомненнно, что молот всегда ассоциировался с наиболее важной, ответственной и тяжелой физической работой. Скорее всего подразумевается молот кузнечный.

А "труда" добавили, видимо, для различения с музыкальным тезкой. Хотя в принципе тот тоже сгодился бы на роли примерного рабочего: ударные инструменты в оркестре на особом положении, они как бы ритм задают. Впрочем, в музыке не силен.

Answer (score 3):

Ударник-это историзм. Слово в этом значении появилось в 20-е-30-е годы, когда трудом  " ударяли" по пережиткам капитализма  и плохой жизни: ◆ Около кузни висел на плетне возглас, нарисованный по флагу: «За партию, за верность ей, за ударный труд, пробивающий пролетариату двери в будущее». А. П. Платонов, «Котлован», 1930 г. (цитата из Национального корпуса русского языка) http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA
Передовой работник социалистического предприятия как бы сравнивался с ударяющей, главной  деталью и механизма, и огнестрельного оружия, с помощью которого боролись с врагами, а врагов тогда видели во всех и во всём.Это как бы такой молот, который пробивает стены, убирает любые преграды на пути рабочего государства.

Так что ударник - от "удар", только в переносном смысле.

Comment: А в чем переносный смысл-то?  

Вот и Вики как-то не очень склонна считать что "ударный труд" - это "удар по пережиткам".    
//=======    
Уда́рник — работник, демонстрирующий повышенную производительность труда. Это понятие зародилось в Советском Союзе в годы первых пятилеток.    
    
Слово связано с выражением «ударный труд», то есть труд с полным напряжением сил, ориентированный на превышение установленных норм и сроков. Также было распространено выражение «ударная бригада»
//=======

Comment: Есть удар в прямом смысле (резкий толчок, звук), а есть в переносном - стремительное нападение, а также неприятность. Вот фразеологизм "в ударе" основан на переносном значении "в состоянии подъёма, когда дело спорится".Удар по чему-то (по капитализму, плохой жизни)-переносное значение.

Comment: А насчёт Вики, моя цитата как раз оттуда

Comment: Цитата оттуда, но она не подтверждает Вашу версию.